# Windows 8.1, moving files between drives with overwrite

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, copy-paste

I have 2 file backup drives that are not in sync. In order to make sure that I have a complete copy, I would like to move all the files from drive 1 to drive 2 and overwrite them. That way, drive 2 will be a merge of both drives' contents. I can then copy all the files back to emptied drive 1.

When doing this in Windows Explorer (Win 8.1), I'm getting an error that says that I don't have enough space. That's actually not the case because there's a big overlap in those two drives.

How can I execute the move that I have just described without having to deal with such an error?

Thnaks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a sync program to sync the 2 files - e.g. the free version of **[Allway Sync](http://allwaysync.com/)** or any other.